# Width is not streching to meet the contraint using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard

So I'm trying to make my design stretch to full width on iphone 6, but for some reason the constraint is not doing what I want it to.

[image]

The lower arrow's width is way larger than 10.

What could the problem be and is there anything else you need to see from me to debug the problem?

The superview is a ScrollView with the horizontal scroll disabled for what its worth...

Comment: UIScrollView contentView doesn't have a fixed content size (that's why it scrolls). To get around this you can put your views inside a view inside the scrollview. Then set the view width equal to the viewController view width.

Comment: @Fogmeister, how can I do that on the Storyboard? Or do I have to do it programatically?

Comment: Do it in the storyboard. Just put a view down first before adding your labels and buttons :)

Comment: I'm doing that, but that view is not spanning the whole width either...

Comment: Add a constraint to it to make the width the same as the main view width (not the scrollview)

Comment: Ok, it appears as I'm on the right track as everything is working fine on the device and simulator, BUT, I'm getting this errors in the storyboard: Ambiguous Layout: Scrollable content size is ambiguous for "Scroll View".

Comment: after you put the equal width on the view then also add a constraint for top bottom left and right between the view and the scrollview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using AutoLayout inside a `UIScrollView`, the `contentSize` of the scroll view is calculated based on the constraints added within the scroll view.

By the looks of things, you want the `contentSize.width` of your scroll view to be equal to the `bounds.size.width` of its superview.

To do this, you can simply add a constraint to your scroll view instructing it to constrain its width to be equal to the width of its superview.

In code, it would be something like this:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
```

Or in Interface Builder, you can simply hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key then drag from the scroll view to its superview to add a **Equal Widths** constraint.

[image: Equal Widths]

Comment: This will only lay out the scrollview and not he content soE of the scroll view.